# ¿Porque react no me esta leyendo mi archivo css?

Tags: css, reactjs

Tengo un problema y es que recién empiezo con react y ya tengo problema, mi problema es que mi código html los componentes no esta leyendo mi archivo css en su defecto también no esta haciendo los cambios pongo aquí mi código de mi archivo .js

```
import React from 'react';
 import styles   from '../css/ButtonModule.css';

     function Saludar( props ) {
    const { nombre = "Sin nombre", saludar } = props;
    return    ( 
         <div>
               <p className={ styles.buttonRed } > Hola { nombre } </p>                   
               <button className = { styles.buttonRed } >Enviar </button>
         </div>   

      );
  } 

   export default Saludar;
```

Este es todo lo que tengo en mi archivo `ButtonModule.css`

```
.buttonRed {
color       : red;
font-size   : 20px;
}
```

pero sin embargo no me muestra nada rojo en la web. 
aqui pongo una imagen de la estructura de las carpetas, archivos etc.

[image: Asi estan mis carpetas y archivos]

Muchas gracias , si hay algo que deba aumentar a la pregunta, con gusto.

Comment: por defecto create-react-app no tiene esa configuracion para usar los estilos asi, tendiras que importar asi ` import  '../css/ButtonModule.css';` y usar las clases normal `className="buttonRed"`. Tendrias que hacer la config de css modules para usarlo como en tu ejemplo

Comment: muchas gracias amigo si me funciono asi solo poniendo entre comillas "buttonREd"

Answer (score 1):

Trata solo importando los estilos, y poniendo las clases como string igual al del html normal

```
import React from 'react';
import '../css/ButtonModule.css';

     function Saludar( props ) {
    const { nombre = "Sin nombre", saludar } = props;
    return    ( 
         <div>
               <p className='buttonRed' > Hola { nombre } </p>                   
               <button className='buttonRed' >Enviar </button>
         </div>   

      );
  } 

   export default Saludar;
```

Answer (score 0):

Te recomendaría hacer todas las importaciones de css en el index.html de tu proyecto de react, una vez declarando tus estilos en el header de tu html el contenedor root de react aplicara todos los cambios de estilo de tu proyecto.

```
<html>
    <header>
       <link href="css/Buttons.css" />
    </header>

    <body>
       <div id="reactDomContainer"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```